# css3 keyframe animation for path in svg symbol tag

Tags: css, animation, svg, path, keyframe

Is it possible to animate a path in the symbol tag with css3 keyframe animation? It doesn't work in my case.

**Example:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hfbmr

**HTML:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
<symbol id="icon-love" viewBox="0 0 54 54">
        <title>Love</title> 
        <path id="icon-love-circle" fill="#000000" d="M27,3c13.2,0,24,10.8,24,24S40.2,51,27,51S3,40.2,3,27S13.8,3,27,3 M27,0C12.1,0,0,12.1,0,27
        s12.1,27,27,27s27-12.1,27-27S41.9,0,27,0L27,0z"/>
        <path id="icon-love-heart" fill="#000000" d="M15.2,23.2c0-2,0.6-3.5,1.7-4.6c1.1-1.1,2.7-1.7,4.7-1.7c0.6,0,1.1,0.1,1.7,0.3c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.5,1.6,0.8
        c0.5,0.3,0.9,0.6,1.3,0.9c0.4,0.3,0.7,0.6,1,0.9c0.3-0.3,0.7-0.6,1-0.9c0.4-0.3,0.8-0.6,1.3-0.9c0.5-0.3,1-0.6,1.6-0.8
        c0.6-0.2,1.1-0.3,1.7-0.3c2,0,3.6,0.6,4.7,1.7c1.1,1.1,1.7,2.6,1.7,4.6c0,2-1,4-3.1,6l-8.3,8c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.2
        c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.6-0.2l-8.4-8.1c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.5-0.7-0.9c-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.9-1.3
        c-0.3-0.4-0.5-1-0.7-1.6C15.4,24.4,15.2,23.8,15.2,23.2z M17,23.2c0,1.5,0.8,3.1,2.5,4.8l7.8,7.5L35,28c1.7-1.7,2.5-3.3,2.5-4.8
        c0-0.7-0.1-1.4-0.3-1.9c-0.2-0.6-0.4-1-0.7-1.3c-0.3-0.3-0.7-0.6-1.1-0.8c-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.3-1.3-0.4c-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.1-1.3-0.1
        s-1,0.1-1.5,0.3c-0.5,0.2-1,0.5-1.5,0.9c-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.7-1.2,1c-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.8,0.8c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.3
        s-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.8-0.8c-0.3-0.3-0.7-0.6-1.2-1c-0.5-0.3-0.9-0.6-1.5-0.9c-0.5-0.2-1-0.3-1.5-0.3
        c-0.5,0-0.9,0-1.3,0.1c-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.2-1.3,0.4c-0.4,0.2-0.8,0.5-1.1,0.8c-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.8-0.7,1.3C17.1,21.8,17,22.5,17,23.2z"
        />
</symbol>
```

**CSS:**

```
.icon-love {
height: 54px;     
width: 54px;
}

#icon-love-heart {
animation-name: 'heartbeat';
animation-duration: 5000ms;
transform-origin:70% 70%;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes heartbeat {
0% { transform: scale(1); }
30% { transform: scale(1); }
40% { transform: scale(1.08); }
50% { transform: scale(1); }
60% { transform: scale(1); }
70% { transform: scale(1.05); }
80% { transform: scale(1); }
100% { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

Cheers Philip

Comment: More than 6 years have passed, and the sprite approach on **svg > use** still does not work, because it is impossible to throw the **@keyframes** CSS selector inside the Shadow DOM

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly possible. It works if you drop `<use xlink:href="#icon-love"/>` part and just use normal svg. If you are concenrned about maintaining your code clean I suggest you store your svg in a variable and output it dynamically instead of using the `<use>` tag, which breaks the animation.

http://codepen.io/easwee/pen/xFDbu

```
<svg class="icon-love" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 54 54">
<path id="icon-love-circle" fill="#000000" d="M27,3c13.2,0,24,10.8,24,24S40.2,51,27,51S3,40.2,3,27S13.8,3,27,3 M27,0C12.1,0,0,12.1,0,27
            s12.1,27,27,27s27-12.1,27-27S41.9,0,27,0L27,0z"/>
<path class="icon-love-heart" fill="#000000" d="M15.2,23.2c0-2,0.6-3.5,1.7-4.6c1.1-1.1,2.7-1.7,4.7-1.7c0.6,0,1.1,0.1,1.7,0.3c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.5,1.6,0.8
            c0.5,0.3,0.9,0.6,1.3,0.9c0.4,0.3,0.7,0.6,1,0.9c0.3-0.3,0.7-0.6,1-0.9c0.4-0.3,0.8-0.6,1.3-0.9c0.5-0.3,1-0.6,1.6-0.8
            c0.6-0.2,1.1-0.3,1.7-0.3c2,0,3.6,0.6,4.7,1.7c1.1,1.1,1.7,2.6,1.7,4.6c0,2-1,4-3.1,6l-8.3,8c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.2
            c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.6-0.2l-8.4-8.1c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.5-0.7-0.9c-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.9-1.3
            c-0.3-0.4-0.5-1-0.7-1.6C15.4,24.4,15.2,23.8,15.2,23.2z M17,23.2c0,1.5,0.8,3.1,2.5,4.8l7.8,7.5L35,28c1.7-1.7,2.5-3.3,2.5-4.8
            c0-0.7-0.1-1.4-0.3-1.9c-0.2-0.6-0.4-1-0.7-1.3c-0.3-0.3-0.7-0.6-1.1-0.8c-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.3-1.3-0.4c-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.1-1.3-0.1
            s-1,0.1-1.5,0.3c-0.5,0.2-1,0.5-1.5,0.9c-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.7-1.2,1c-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.8,0.8c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.3
            s-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.8-0.8c-0.3-0.3-0.7-0.6-1.2-1c-0.5-0.3-0.9-0.6-1.5-0.9c-0.5-0.2-1-0.3-1.5-0.3
            c-0.5,0-0.9,0-1.3,0.1c-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.2-1.3,0.4c-0.4,0.2-0.8,0.5-1.1,0.8c-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.8-0.7,1.3C17.1,21.8,17,22.5,17,23.2z"
            />
</svg>
```

Also added prefixes for crossbrowser css (webkit, firefox and standard):

```
.icon-love {width:54px;height:54px;}

.icon-love-heart {
 -moz-animation: heartbeat 5s linear infinite; 
  -webkit-animation: heartbeat 5s linear infinite; 
  animation: heartbeat 5s linear infinite;
   -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%;
 -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    transform-origin:50% 50%;

}

@-moz-keyframes heartbeat {
    0% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
    30% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
    40% { -moz-transform: scale(1.08); }
    50% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
    60% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
    70% { -moz-transform: scale(1.05); }
    80% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
    100% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
}


@-webkit-keyframes heartbeat {
    0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    30% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    40% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.08); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    70% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.05); }
    80% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
}

@keyframes heartbeat {
    0% { transform: scale(1); }
    30% { transform: scale(1); }
    40% { transform: scale(1.08); }
    50% { transform: scale(1); }
    60% { transform: scale(1); }
    70% { transform: scale(1.05); }
    80% { transform: scale(1); }
    100% { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I killed the vendor prefixes for this example an put the svg inline for this example. In my development environment the svg is a external file.

The Problem is, that I need <use xlink:href="#icon-love"/> because it is a svg sprite. Like here: http://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/

Comment: @Philip To make that work I would need to dig in - maybe tonight if I can catch some time. Hope you solve it by then.

Comment: @Philip 2 years later and problem still occurs. Did you find any solution or workaround ?

Comment: The question was about doing it using SVG symbols, so I think the correct answer is: No. It is not possible.

Comment: @Nevitones if you open his original problematic sample you would see that it actually animates - so this is possible in 2020 and is not an issue anymore.